# How is the Shininess of a blinn material calculated by the Collada (dae) - exporter?

Tags: 3d, maya, collada

I'm using Maya 2013 and the fbx_dae-exporter.
When I export a 3d-model with a blinn material with the Eccentricity set to 0.3 the shininess in the dae-file is set to 1.245731

I would like to support collada 1.5 in my application and I get different values from different exporters. What I do is a mapping to [1,128] if the value is between 0 and 1, which won't work for Maya-exported dae-files.

How is the shininess calculated by the Maya-exporter?
In the source-code of the opencollada-project I found a converter BlinnEccentricityToShininess which calculates it like this:

```
100.0f - 99.0f * sqrtf ( v )
```

I assume Maya 2013 doesn't use this converter since I get different results.

---

I noticed that this only happens when I import a dae before where this value was already set.

Comment: What I can suggest you to do is try to export different time different values, like: 0, 0.5, 1 and try to extract a function that converts the eccentricity into the shininess. More values means more accurate results, of course, specially if you have non linear conversions.